# Terminal question linux

Tags: command-line

im new in Linux and in my terminal i got this Downloads$ before typing a command. Is there a way to change it or remove it?
For example: 
elementary@elementary-laptop: ~/Downloads$

Comment: The possible duplicate answer is a godo answer, read through that and welcome to Linux! :D

Comment: sorry it did not help me.

Comment: Change it to what? Do `cd` or `cd ~/Desktop` if you just want to change the directory.